# How to get the sibling element of a parent element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Today I was trying to trigger the tooltip of a particular element when I hovered over a different element. I'm not that experienced in jQuery, but I eventually got this to work reading through the docs. Afterwards, I saw how I referenced the target element and it seemed really convoluted. I was wondering if there were better methods that could produce the same results.

The HTML I'm working with is as follows:

```
<div class="item">
    <h3 class="level-title">ITEM 1
        <span class="level-label" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-animation="true" title="Tooltip text that pops up">Title Text
        </span>
    </h3>
    <div class="level-bar">
        <div class="level-bar-inner" data-level="70%">
        </div>                                      
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <h3 class="level-title">ITEM 2
        <span class="level-label" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-animation="true" title="Tooltip text that pops up">Title Text
        </span>
    </h3>
    <div class="level-bar">
        <div class="level-bar-inner" data-level="70%">
        </div>                                      
    </div>
</div>
```

In my HTML file I have 5 or so of those item sections. What I wanted was for the tooltip to not only trigger when a viewer moused over the "Title Text", but also when they hovered over the "level-bar-inner" div. To I achieve this I came up with the following piece of JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
...
    $('.level-bar-inner').hover(
        function(e) {
            $($($(e.target).parent().siblings()[0]).children()[0]).tooltip('show');
        },
        function(e) {
            $($($(e.target).parent().siblings()[0]).children()[0]).tooltip('hide');
        }
    );
...
});
```

It seemed like a sloppy solution but a reasonable one. This method hinges on there being only one sibling and one child, which fortunately in my case was true for all the "item" sections in my HTML file. Which leads me to asking if there are better/more efficient methods of retrieving this element or even just toggling it's tooltip in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reference the element that raised the event using the `this` keyword. You can also use jQuery's DOM traversal methods, instead of repeatedly getting a DOMElement from a jQuery object, and turning it back in to a jQuery object again. Try this:

```
$('.level-bar-inner').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().prev().find('span').tooltip('show');
}, function(e) {
    $(this).parent().prev().find('span').tooltip('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You better go all the way up to the parent `.item` then it would be much easier to find the corresponding tooltip element:

```
$('.level-bar-inner').hover(
    function() {
       $(this).parents('.item').find('.level-label').tooltip('show');
    },
    function() {
       $(this).parents('.item').find('.level-label').tooltip('hide');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` other than `e.target`. Along with that the `prev` element is probably what you are looking for, then get the child by it's class:

```
$('.level-bar-inner').hover(
    function(e) {
        $(this).parent().prev().child(".level-label").tooltip('show');
    },
    function(e) {
        $(this).parent().prev().child(".level-label").tooltip('hide');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it if you are following the same structure of adding data attributes to the elements, would be

```
$('.level-bar-inner').hover(function(e) {
$(this).closest('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip('show');
}, function(e) {
$(this).closest('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip('hide');
});
```